# Is there a natural topology for the set of measurable sets (i.e. a given sigma algebra)?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, algebraic-topology, topological-data-analysis

Given a sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$, is there a natural topology worth defining on it? More specifically, is there a topology you can put on $\mathcal{F}$ which ensures a measure of interest $\mu: \mathcal{F} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous? Moreover are there any known guarantees regarding whether the resulting topological space is triangulable?

EDIT: Thanks for the answers everyone. I thought I'd explain a little bit more why I am interested in this problem. In [Topological Data Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_data_analysis) it is fairly common to investigate the persistent homology of the sublevel sets of density functions. I wanted to know if something similar could be done for probability measures. That is, is it *possible* to compute persistence diagrams for probability distribution functions. To do so, I need an underlying topology for $\mathcal{F}$ for which 1) the topology is triangulable and 2) any measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{F}$ is tame. Now, I don't plan to actually compute these persistent diagrams, but I wondered if there would be any provable relationship between the persistence diagram of a distribution function and the persistence diagram of its corresponding density. To do so, I first need to verify whether computing a persistence diagram on the sublevel sets of a distribution function even "makes sense".

EDIT 2: I am using the following definition of tame functions, from [here](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eshmuel/AAT-readings/Data%20Analysis%20/Edelsbrunner,%20Harer,%20Stability.pdf):
[image]

Comment: I mean, you can just pick the coarsest topology on $\mathcal F$ that ensures that $\mu$ is continuous... I don't see why such a guarantee of triangulability would exist. It's probably not too hard to come up with a counterexample.

Comment: What is meant by "tame measure"?

Comment: @AlephBeth I have updated the question with the definition and a link with more details.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a comment, but far too long. From the point of view of measure theory, there is no natural T2 topology on the $\sigma$-algebra of a measure space~$(X,\sigma,\mu)$.
Compare the case of subsets of a metric space $(Y,d)$. In order to obtain a reasonable topology, one needs not distinguish between $A$ and $\overline A$ (closure), which are indeed indistinguishable from the point of view of the functional $d(A,\cdot)$ (the analogue of the functional $\mu$ in this example). In this case one restricts one's attention to closed subsets, defining the *Hausdorff topology* on the set of closed subsets of $(X,d)$.

For measure-theoretical purposes (but I am sure the OP's interest is beyond this, because of the triangulability question), the natural thing to do is identify two sets $A_1,A_2\in \Sigma$ if $\mu(A_1\triangle A_2)=0$ ($\triangle$ being the symmetric difference). More formally, let $\Sigma^\mu$ be the Carathéodory $\mu$-completion of $\Sigma$ and $\mathcal N^\mu$ be the $\sigma$-ideal of $\mu$-negligible subsets of $X$.
The *measure algebra* $(\mathfrak A, \bar\mu)$ of $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is defined as the quotient of $\mathfrak A$ of $\Sigma^\mu$ by $\mathcal N^\mu$, endowed with the quotient functional $\bar\mu$.
In the following, write $a=[A]\in\mathfrak A$ for the class of $A\in\Sigma$, and note that $0=0_{\mathfrak A}=[\varnothing]$ and $1=1_{\mathfrak A}=[X]$ (as usual the product is just $\cap$, and $\mathfrak A$ is a Bolean algebra with this product).

At this point I should remark that much information on both the space $X$ and the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ is lost, since there is a Procrustean bed of measure spaces with isomorphic measure algebras.

For simplicity, I assume from now on that $\mu$ is finite. Much of what follows can be generalized to the $\sigma$-finite case at least. A natural *uniformity* is defined on $(\mathfrak A,\bar \mu)$ by the family of pseudo-metrics (triangle inequality, symmetry, but possibly vanishing outside the diagonal):
$$\rho_a(b,c):= \bar\mu\big(a\cap (b\triangle c)\big)\,.$$

The topology induced by this uniformity is very closely related to the topology of convergence in measure on the space of functions $L^0(\mu)$.
When $\bar \mu$ is finite (here: by assumption), the uniformity (hence the topology) is induced by the <s>pseudo-</s>metric $\rho_1$.
From the point of view of measure theory, this topology is quite natural, e.g., since it allows to neglect the fine properties of adherence of $\Sigma$ to $X$.

Comment: What does  represent here? Is it some boolean algebra derived from $\Sigma^{\mu}$? Apologies I am unfamiliar.

Comment: I think I see what you are getting at... So I can use the topology induced by the pseudometric $\rho_{1}$ to prove results regarding convergence in measure in the space of functions $L^{0}(\mu)$?

Comment: $\mathfrak A$ represents the algebra of classes of sets up to $\mu$-a.e. equivalence (in the same way as you have different representatives for the class of a measurable function). Indeed if $\mu$ is finite it is the case that one can define convergence in measure via the convergence of $\mu$-classes of preimages, but this is not entirely straightforward. I should mention (for I forgot to write this in the answer) that $\bar\mu$ is trivially continuous on $\mathfrak A$, which answers the first part of your question.